# Consulta Entidade sem suas Associações

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou criando uma aplicação com `JAVA SE` + `HIBERNATE`. Estou tendo um "problema" em fazer uma consulta a uma única Entidade. Então, teria como fazer uma consulta na entidade(`TABELA`) sem o mapeamento relacional `@One-to-One,@One-to-Many, @Many-to-One, @Many-to-Many` ?

Agradeço desde já pela compreensão

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Os relacionamentos só existem para facilitar a recuperação das informações relacionadas a uma entidade. Sem eles seria necessário projetar as consultas explicitando joins e portanto perdendo de certa forma o poder que o Hibernate provê.

Se o motivo do não uso de mapeamento for pelo fato das consultas trazerem muitas informações ou demorarem, você pode sempre utilizar o `FetchType.LAZY` nos mapeamentos que você possui.
Utilizando dessa forma, é como se não existisse mapeamento pois os dados do relacionamento só serão carregados se você explicitamente utilizá-los (chamando um get pro objeto ou um iterator para a collection).

É importante frisar que sem os mapeamentos nenhuma entidade que não represente um tipo suportado no banco de dados poderá ser atribuída a um atributo sem o devido mapeamento.
Essa restrição existe porque o hibernate não tem como saber qual tabela a entidade representa sem que seja explicitado a ele através de anotações ou configuração de arquivo xml (*hibernate.cfg.xml*).